# PySpark: Adding new rows for missing dates grouped by unique value in another Column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
date                 ID        Val
-------------------------------------
2017-09-01           1          2
2017-09-03           1          3
2017-09-05           1          4 
2017-09-05           2          1   
2017-09-07           2          2
```

What I want is something like this:

```
date                 ID        Val
-------------------------------------
2017-09-01           1          2
2017-09-02           1          NULL
2017-09-03           1          3
2017-09-04           1          NULL
2017-09-05           1          4
2017-09-05           2          1   
2017-09-06           2          NULL
2017-09-07           2          2
```

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve looping over unique IDs, filtering and then collecting min and max dates?